# Group by continuous indexes in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on code for sensors data analysis using python.

I'm taking rows from DataFrame (of gyro data in the example) according to some condition.

```
import pandas as pd

gyro = pd.read_csv("gyroOutput.csv")
above = gyro[gyro['gyro_z'] > 0.30]

above
Out[162]: 
        gyro_x    gyro_y    gyro_z  elapsed
27    0.026632  0.021305  0.305731    4.927
28    0.017044  0.011718  0.344080    5.115
29    0.008522  0.013848  0.380299    5.289
30    0.006392  0.026632  0.412257    5.470
31    0.007457  0.005326  0.448476    5.643
32   -0.004261  0.012783  0.465521    5.822
33   -0.001065  0.000000  0.452737    6.002
34    0.009587  0.006392  0.445281    6.181
35    0.010653  0.001065  0.412257    6.361
36    0.006392  0.003196  0.373908    6.543
37   -0.006392  0.007457  0.320645    6.722
108  -0.036219  0.052198  0.323840   19.470
109  -0.061785 -0.001065  0.389887   19.654
110  -0.049002  0.018109  0.453803   19.835
111  -0.038350  0.078830  0.513458   20.015
112  -0.034088  0.011718  0.555003   20.192
113  -0.005326 -0.001065  0.607201   20.374
114   0.009587  0.058590  0.629571   20.553
115   0.038350 -0.029827  0.598679   20.727
116   0.006392  0.013848  0.546481   20.907
117   0.007457  0.030893  0.478304   21.086
118   0.012783 -0.035154  0.446346   21.266
119   0.005326 -0.026632  0.367516   21.444
352   0.007457  0.028762  0.313188   63.284
353   0.006392 -0.011718  0.332363   63.463
354   0.008522  0.030893  0.378169   63.643
355  -0.015979  0.039415  0.409062   63.822
356  -0.009587 -0.022371  0.423975   64.002
357  -0.008522  0.023436  0.450607   64.181
358  -0.011718  0.047937  0.453803   64.361
```

That result data frame (above) holds groups of continuous indexes rows. For example, lines 27-37.

I want to get all those group's, couldn't find any way to do it using DataFrame.groupby or any other function.

I could iterate over the rows and separate them myself, but maybe there's some simpler way using pandas functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [294]: df.groupby(df.index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum()).groups
Out[294]:
{1: Int64Index([27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37], dtype='int64'),
 2: Int64Index([108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119], dtype='int64'),
 3: Int64Index([352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358], dtype='int64')}
```

Comment: All these time I was looking at the values rather than index. Something is wrong with me today

Comment: @Dark, get some rest :)